# ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' Angular 10

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am getting [ng] ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' this error. I searched a lot but not getting exact solution. I will be highly thankful if someone give me any idea or any help. I am sharing IONIC and other environment.

```
Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.9 (C:\Users\pushpa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1001.2
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
@angular/cli                  : 10.1.2
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Utility:
cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:
NodeJS : v12.18.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.14.6
OS     : Windows 10
```

My app.module.ts file code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can anyone suggest where i am wrong as i globally installed latest version of IONIC, CORDOVA, NODE of all. I am trying from past 2 days but not succeed. I am attaching screenshot pls find.

[image: IONIC SERVE IMAGE]

My Package.json File

```
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Thanks in ADVANCE.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Not yet. I am still looking for solution for this. Even I tried reinstall node_modules but not worked @DamianC

Comment: Are you using angular material? I had this issue yesterday and I resolved it by updating the ng update @angular/cdk @angular/material rxjs. Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: Hii @DamianC 
Sorry for late reply.

I uploaded my package.json in question. can you please look at this.

Thanks